# Center div vertically and horizontally center even when page scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display a div vertically and horizontally center, and this works fine, but when I scroll down the page and try the link at the bottom (it is a comment box) then it displays at the top of the page, not in the screen, and you need to scroll up to use it. How can I get it centered even if the user has scrolled down?

Here is my code so far (from the research I have done):

```
$("#comment").css('top', ((screen.height / 2) - ($('#comment').height()/2))+'px');
$("#comment").css('left', (screen.width / 2) - ($('#comment').width()/2)+'px');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `position:fixed` instead of absolute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to do this via JQuery?
Maybe you can just CSS style it?

CSS

```
#commentBox {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    height:240px;
    width:70%;
    padding:15px;
    border:1px dashed #333;
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

Look at my example: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Olavxxx/KLbcy/)

Answer (score 0):

[.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

```
var comment = $("#comment"),
    com = $('#com');
$(window).scroll(function () {
    comment.css('top', ((screen.height / 2) - (com.height() / 2)) + 'px');
    comment.css('left', (screen.width / 2) - (com.width() / 2) + 'px');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same issue