# Animate a div when the user can see it

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

How can I move/bounce a div when the user can see it while scrolling the page? Without knowing the position of the scrollbar... Is it possible via html5/css only?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS and apply the fixed property to your div. For example:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>

.fixedposition{
position: fixed;
top:100px;
left:100px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class = "fixedposition">Awesome content</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So to answer the other part of your question, it absolutely is possible with just HTML5 and CSS. You can use JavaScript and JQuery as well if you wish.

Comment: Also I just want to point out that if you search it up, there are multiple questions that address a problem similar to yours, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882737/center-div-vertically-and-horizontally-center-even-when-page-scrolled-down?rq=1. Make sure to research your issue thoroughly. =)

Comment: you may want to add some other declarations like either `top` or `bottom`, then `left` or `right` so that you are explicitly setting the anchor location.